# Get elements of an array in date range

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is an example document in my MongoDB collection:

```js
 var user: [{
            "_id" : ObjectId("5391b11a3c0a9ac01300006d"),
            "injurydata" : {                
                "injuryinformation" : [ 
                    {
                        "status" : "current",
                        "updateddate" : ISODate("2014-06-06T12:16:20.306Z"),
                        "updatedby" : "",
                        "dateofinjury" : ISODate("2014-06-27T18:30:00.000Z"),                          
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5391b11a3c0a9ac01300006f")
                    }                   
                ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5391b11a3c0a9ac01300006d"),
            "injurydata" : {                
                "injuryinformation" : [ 
                    {
                        "status" : "current",
                        "updateddate" : ISODate("2014-06-06T12:16:20.306Z"),                           
                        "dateofinjury" : ISODate("2014-06-28T18:30:00.000Z"),                            
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5391b11a3c0a9ac01300006f")
                    }                   
                ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5391b11a3c0a9ac01300006d"),
            "injurydata" : {                
                "injuryinformation" : [ 
                    {
                        "status" : "current",                            
                        "dateofinjury" : ISODate("2014-08-10T18:30:00.000Z"),                            
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5391b11a3c0a9ac01300006f")
                    }                   
                ]
            }
         }]
```

From this document, I want only those `injuryinformation` array elements for which `dateofinJURY` is between 2014-06-28 and 2014-06-30, so I will only get first two elements.

I tried this query but I still get the whole array

```js
db.user.find(
{
    $and: 
    [
        {"injury.injurydata.injuryinformation.dateofinjury": 
        {"$gte": ISODate("2014-05-21T08:00:00Z") , "$lt": ISODate("2014-06- 03T08:00:00Z")}},       
        {"_id":ObjectId("538d9a1dd173e5202a00005d")}
    ],

})
```

Comment: See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/

Comment: i checked this link but my collection have multiple array so cant find any solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the `_id` match is fairly explicit in your statement so not only will that negate the need for the "range" match on array entries but it also negates any usage of [**`$and`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) which is actually implicit in MongoDB queries. The [**`$and`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) condition is essentially the "default" and is not required unless you are actually asking for multiple conditions on te same field. But here you are not.

Matching multiple array elements you need to use [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) as the "projection" available to `.find()` cannot show you more than **one** matching entry from an array:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([

    // Match the document but not actually the array
    { "$match": {
        "injury.injurydata.injuryinformation.dateofinjury": {
            "$gte": ISODate("2014-05-21T08:00:00Z"), 
            "$lt": ISODate("2014-06-03T08:00:00Z")
        },       
        "_id": ObjectId("538d9a1dd173e5202a00005d")
    }},

    // Unwind the arrays to "de-normalize" as documents
    { "$unwind": "$injury" },
    { "$unwind": "$injury.injurydata" }, 
    { "$unwind": "$injury.injurydata.injuryinformation" },

    // Match the actual array elements
    { "$match": {
        "injury.injurydata.injuryinformation.dateofinjury": {
            "$gte": ISODate("2014-05-21T08:00:00Z"), 
            "$lt": ISODate("2014-06-03T08:00:00Z")
        }
    }},

    // Group those back to and array, maybe?
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "information": {
            "$push": "$injury.injrydata.injuryinformation"
        }
    }}
])
```

Or "filtering" with [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) under MongoDB 2.6 and greater, looks longer but faster:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([

    // Match the document but not actually the array
    { "$match": {
        "injury.injurydata.injuryinformation.dateofinjury": {
            "$gte": ISODate("2014-05-21T08:00:00Z"), 
            "$lt": ISODate("2014-06-03T08:00:00Z")
        },       
        "_id": ObjectId("538d9a1dd173e5202a00005d")
    }},

    // Unwind the arrays to "de-normalize" as documents
    { "$unwind": "$injury" },
    { "$unwind": "$injury.injurydata" }, 

    // Project with the "$map" filter
    { "$project": {
        "information": {
            "$setDifference": [
                "$map": {
                    "input": "$injury.injurydata.injuryinformation",
                    "as": "el",
                    "in": {
                        "$cond": [
                            {
                                "$and": [
                                    { 
                                        "$gte": [ 
                                            "$$el.dateofinjury",
                                            ISODate("2014-05-21T08:00:00Z")
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "$lt": [
                                            "$$el.dateofinjury",
                                            ISODate("2014-06-03T08:00:00Z")
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        false
                    }
                },
                [false]
            ]
        }
    }}

])
```

The **$and** condition used in there is a different form that is available to aggregation framework expressions outside of **`$match`** operations that are equivalent to .`find()` queries.

Not sure where the "injury" top line comes from there as it is not represented in your sample, but I assume you actually have it.

Comment: i tried 1st query but still i am getting result:Array[0]

Comment: @MaTya I did notice I had missed two `$unwind` statements. You could make this easier for people to test against by including better data in your samples. What you have included is an unwound array that guessing from your previous question as to what the actual structure is. Also the `$match` values in your query are not present in the data sample. But the process there will essentially work just as long as your data and field paths are correct.